# Google HTML Meta Tag verification Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-search-console

How can i add Google HTML meta tag verification in wordpress in blog page only

i.e `mydomainname.com/blogs` only not in any other pages

```
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="verification code" />
```

any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Since you have tagged this with Google Analytics I suggest you use your GA account for verification (else you might as well remove the tag, this is not an Analytics question).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you not want to verify your entire site?

Comment: @Craig client wants to verify only the blogs page only not any other pages and he just send me only this code and his verification url is mydomainname.com/blogs